# what is the sql logic for check weather workflow completed within time or not in informatica?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud, informatica-powerexchange

I have to put the logic for workflow that weather that workflow completed within time or not.
suppose i want my workflow should be complete within 1 hr so, what will be the logic for this. I have start time of the workflow.

Comment: isnt it a duplicate of your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70922690/what-will-be-the-query-for-check-completion-of-workflow ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what will be the query for check completion of workflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70922690/what-will-be-the-query-for-check-completion-of-workflow)